# How to troubleshoot "NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:"?

Tags: python

I don't understand why I'm receiving this an error.

**Error:**

```
File "/home/user/my_script.py", line 37, in my_script
    os.replace(temp_file.name, file_name)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/user/folder/tmpep07qkgk' -> '/home/user/folder/'
```

**My code:**

```
file_name = config['filename']
file_format = config['format']

if file_format == 'yml':
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', dir=os.path.dirname(file_name), delete=False) as temp_file:
        yaml.safe_dump(convert_to_dict(data), temp_file)
    os.replace(temp_file.name, file_name) # LINE 37
    logger.info('Saved to file: {}'.format(file_name))
```

Comment: can you show what's the value of `file_name` ?

Comment: Yes - `filename = /home/user/test/`

Comment: well, `temp_file` is a file while `filename` is actually a directory path... (as it ends with `/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `file_name` is a file path. Both parameters of `os.rename` have to be either a file path or a directory path. Or you'll get an error.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace

Here's a working example

```py
import tempfile
import os

t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('a')

dest_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, 'saved.yml')

print(t.name)
print(dest_path)

os.replace(t.name, dest_path)

print(os.path.isfile(dest_path))
```

output:

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwcs1m87w
C:\Users\x\saved.yml
True
```